hosted ChromaDB as retriever in Langchain RetrievalQA
I'm hosting a chromadb instance in an AWS instance. I want to use the vector database as retriever for a RAG pipeline using Langchain.
All the examples and documentation use
Chroma.from_texts()
to load the documents from a local folder, but I want to use my hosted dataset.
model = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="geminipro",temperature=0.2,convert_system_message_to_human=True)


template = """ My template.
            {context}
            Question: {question}
            Answer: """

QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)


#here i connect to the chromadb instance
chroma_client = chromadb.HttpClient(
                                host="localhost",
                                port=8000,
                                ssl=False,
                                headers=None,
                                settings=Settings(),
                                tenant=DEFAULT_TENANT,
                                database=DEFAULT_DATABASE,
                            )

google_ef  = embedding_functions.GoogleGenerativeAiEmbeddingFunction(api_key="MY_API_KEY")
db = Chroma(client=chroma_client, collection_name="documents",embedding_function=google_ef)

retriever = db.as_retriever()

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    model,
    retriever=retriever,
    return_source_documents=True,
    chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT}
)

question = "Che lavori ha fatto la società FOCAL SRL??"
result = qa_chain({"query": question})
result["result"]
     

But I get as error : AttributeError: 'GoogleGenerativeAiEmbeddingFunction' object has no attribute 'embed_query'
this is the stack trace :
/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/__init__.py:29: UserWarning: Importing PromptTemplate from langchain root module is no longer supported. Please use langchain_core.prompts.PromptTemplate instead.
  warnings.warn(
/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/_api/module_import.py:92: LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing PyPDFLoader from langchain.document_loaders is deprecated. Please replace deprecated imports:

>> from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

with new imports of:

>> from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
You can use the langchain cli to **automatically** upgrade many imports. Please see documentation here https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/versions/v0_2/ 
  warn_deprecated(
/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/_api/module_import.py:92: LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing Chroma from langchain.vectorstores is deprecated. Please replace deprecated imports:

>> from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

with new imports of:

>> from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
You can use the langchain cli to **automatically** upgrade many imports. Please see documentation here https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/versions/v0_2/ 
  warn_deprecated(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 715, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 244, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1285, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1331, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1040, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x12d86d370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 667, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 799, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/tenants/default_tenant (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x12d86d370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 438, in _validate_tenant_database
    self._admin_client.get_tenant(name=tenant)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 486, in get_tenant
    return self._server.get_tenant(name=name)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/telemetry/opentelemetry/__init__.py", line 143, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/fastapi.py", line 182, in get_tenant
    resp = self._session.get(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 700, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/tenants/default_tenant (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x12d86d370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/rag.py", line 45, in <module>
    chroma_client = chromadb.HttpClient(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 197, in HttpClient
    return ClientCreator(tenant=tenant, database=database, settings=settings)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 144, in __init__
    self._validate_tenant_database(tenant=tenant, database=database)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 440, in _validate_tenant_database
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not connect to a Chroma server. Are you sure it is running?
(env) (base) amedeo@MBP-di-Amedeo env % python3 rag.py
/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/__init__.py:29: UserWarning: Importing PromptTemplate from langchain root module is no longer supported. Please use langchain_core.prompts.PromptTemplate instead.
  warnings.warn(
/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/_api/module_import.py:92: LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing PyPDFLoader from langchain.document_loaders is deprecated. Please replace deprecated imports:

>> from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

with new imports of:

>> from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
You can use the langchain cli to **automatically** upgrade many imports. Please see documentation here https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/versions/v0_2/ 
  warn_deprecated(
/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/_api/module_import.py:92: LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing Chroma from langchain.vectorstores is deprecated. Please replace deprecated imports:

>> from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

with new imports of:

>> from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
You can use the langchain cli to **automatically** upgrade many imports. Please see documentation here https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/versions/v0_2/ 
  warn_deprecated(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/rag.py", line 67, in <module>
    result = qa_chain({"query": question})
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/_api/deprecation.py", line 148, in warning_emitting_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 383, in __call__
    return self.invoke(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 166, in invoke
    raise e
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 156, in invoke
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/chains/retrieval_qa/base.py", line 142, in _call
    docs = self._get_docs(question, run_manager=_run_manager)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/chains/retrieval_qa/base.py", line 254, in _get_docs
    return self.retriever.invoke(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/retrievers.py", line 221, in invoke
    raise e
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/retrievers.py", line 214, in invoke
    result = self._get_relevant_documents(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/vectorstores.py", line 797, in _get_relevant_documents
    docs = self.vectorstore.similarity_search(query, **self.search_kwargs)
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 349, in similarity_search
    docs_and_scores = self.similarity_search_with_score(
  File "/Users/amedeo/Desktop/chroma-client/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 438, in similarity_search_with_score
    query_embedding = self._embedding_function.embed_query(query)
TypeError: embed_query() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'

I cannot find any documentation on how to use a hosted instance as retriever. I'm not really sure if it is the right way to use it or if I should go with a persisted client. The problem is that I have a lot of documents (1000+) so im not really sure if keeping them in a local directory is the right choice.
